# What prevents the x-axis label to appear in a Python tkinter canvas graph?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, axis-labels

I'm plotting a graph in Python and want to label the x-and y-axis appropriately. However, only the y-axis decorator is shown, despite both of them beeing set. What could be preventing the x-axis decorator from displaying properly?

```
y_values = [1, 3, 9, 27]
x_values = [0, 2, 4, 6]

f = Figure(figsize=(6,2), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)

# setting the labels
a.set_xlabel("frequency(Hz)")
a.set_ylabel("Amplitude (mm/s)")  

a.plot(x_values, y_values)
canvasf = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvasf.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 1, column = 3, columnspan = 3)
canvasf.draw()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `Figure` has insufficient height to draw the x-axis label. Try to play with the `figsize` parameters, for example:

```
f = Figure(figsize=(6,4), dpi=100)
```

Comment: Increasing figsize does display both axis decorators. However, the vertical height in my programm is limited. Is there a way to still display the axis decorators without increasing the vertical height of the graph?

Comment: You can set `a = f.add_subplot(211)`, in this case the vertical height of the graph remains unchanged but the vertical scale will be smaller.

Comment: Also you can trade off with all these parameters and `dpi`.